# How do I create Individual Health for each spawned object?

Tags: software-engineering

This question is probably asked many times, but how do I make sure that each time an object is spawned, that said object gains a value representing that objects health.

Basically I have an enemy spawner that creates multiple enemies.

Player shoots at one enemy, the enemy hit should be the only one to take damage, but I have never learned how to do that. Do I have to make the system create a new temporary integer each time a unit is created to represent it's health and then delete the temporary integer once it reaches 0?

I am not asking for help regarding one specific coding language (although c# would be the best), I only want to know a good (or simple) way to create individual health for multiple spawned objects.

Comment: What engine/framework/language are you using?

Comment: "I am not asking for help regarding one specific coding language, I only want to know a good (or simple) way to create individual health for multiple spawned objects." Although C# would help.

Comment: @user106710 give each object its own health.  That is the only way to answer it wthout a specific engine/language/framework.

Comment: @Eddge That would require me to add probably over 300 different values.

Comment: I read (that part) of your question, but you still have to be using some _actual_ language or tools to build your game. Knowing what those tools are, knowing how you _actually_ spawn an object, will let us provide a better answer. Otherwise all we can offer are generalities equivalent to the generality of the question you asked, which probably aren't as helpful as you would like.

Comment: You don't add the health property manually to every enemy _as you create it_, you add it once, to the _type_ representing the enemy. If you have "300" different concrete enemy types, you have a larger design problem you can probably address by electing to build an enemy base class (and put the property there), or using aggregation to add a "basic properties" block of data to every enemy type.

Comment: As others have said, the solution depends on the programming language you are using. If you are using an object-oriented language, it might be interesting to read on the concepts of classes and objects (instances of classes) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215881/the-difference-between-classes-objects-and-instances). C# is an example of an object-oriented language. In short: a class is a "blueprint" that describes the structure of an object (e.g. my object has an integer variable "health"), and an object is a concrete instance of that class (e.g. obj1 has health=123, obj2 has health=456)

Answer (score 8):

Simply make the health a property of the enemy type.

You've presumably got some kind of type or class that represents an entity or a character in your game:

```
class Enemy {
  // ...some stuff...
}
```

If you want each enemy to have a health stat, you can give the `Enemy` type an instance member representing health:

```
class Enemy {
  int health = 100;
  // ...some more stuff...
}
```

If you want them to have a varying amount of health when they spawn, you can pipe that value through whatever construction mechanism exists in your engine and/or language. The above example code is vaguely C#-like pseudo-code; if you were actually using C# you'd probably do this via an `Enemy` constructor, for example:

```
public class Enemy {
  public int CurrentHealth;

  public Enemy(int initialHealth) {
    CurrentHealth = initialHealth;
  }        
}
```

That way, when you create a new `Enemy` from your spawning code, you just pass the desired health: `new Enemy(155)` for example.